# iOS: How to start populating cells in UICollectionview at the half way mark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to start populating my UICollectionView with my cells at the middle and not at the very top. I am not sure if this bit of code will help, but I will post it just in case.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

 Cell *cell = (Cell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSMutableArray *data = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

cell.cellImg.image = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

return cell;
  }
```

Comment: Just fill the first few rows with empty, alphaed-out cells.

Answer (score 0):

Why not populate your array in another order? Take a look on Apple [UICollectionViewDataSource Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView%3acellForItemAtIndexPath%3a):

> "You do not need to set the location of the cell inside the collection
>   view’s bounds. The collection view sets the location of each cell
>   automatically using the layout attributes provided by its layout
>   object."

If you need some more info about Collection View Layout:

**[UICollectionview Layout Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uicollectionview-layouts--mobile-13426)**